# Does uninstalling an Android Application kill any alarms configured?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am creating an Alarm in application to run at 8 Am every morning and process some business logic. Can somebody please confirm if the alarm would be killed/removed automatically when the application is uninstalled ? Or do I need to specifically handle `PACKAGE_REMOVED` intent to remove the alarm ?

Thanks a lot in advance.
Vinay

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `AlarmManager` yes it does. As does force closing the app.

Comment: Yes. I am using Alarm Manager. Thx for the quick response. Cheers